# Is there a performance penalty for storing values in the web.config compared to const fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net, optimization, web-config

currently in our application we have an ApplicationConfiguration class. It is basically just a static class with `const` values specifying certain application-global configuration options. Some of these values will rarely if ever change and are only put into the configuration for elegance/cleanness. . It's currently hardcoded to something like 100, which is good for all practical applications. -->

Some of these values though do need to be different between production and development. So I'm considering making this class just a wrapper over Web.config. These values are checked many times throughout our codebase. If I change these from a `const` to a read-only getter that reads from Web.config will this affect compiler optimizations or make our application in any way slower?

Answer (score 1):

Web.config values are read into memory once in app start, and are held there until the app ends. So, there's no real difference in performance here -- no extra file I/O repeatedly reading web.config.

**One key difference between the two approaches happens when you need to change the value of one of the configuration options.** Changing the value in web.config is relatively easy and may not even require a restart of the application (depends upon how it's configured).

To change the value of a constant, of course, you have to recompile and redeploy your code. That may not be a trivial endeavor.

Comment: redeploying is really not a problem for us. We can do a full redeploy in in about 20-30 minutes and our application is only used by certain people during US working hours(8am-6pm or so) so we have time where we can take the application offline even. That's not a problem.

Comment: That's 20-30 minutes compared to <30 seconds to change the web.config, plus the harzard of doing one of deploy steps incorrectly. But that's production - perhaps a new release (i.e. deploy) is required for any change.

Comment: Well, the only thing you have to do instead for such a change is reupload the website's assembly file which takes about 15 seconds for me in FireFTP.

Comment: Ok, so the point here is that in general the performance between the two options is negligible, but ease and reliability of deployment is a different consideration.  I think the question that we're touching on is how to decide whether a particular value should be a constant or a config setting.  I'm hesitant to make any blanket statements, but one possible rule of thumb is that if a value is internal to the application, then it's fine as a constant; if it relates to an external resource (e.g. database connection string), then it's better as a config setting.